# How to take numbers from 2 loop and make 1 for start and 1 for end number in a new loop

Tags: c++, loops

I can't use numbers from 2 loops to make the begin and end of another for loop
It's just repeat 1 times.

```
int arr[100000];
int N;
int sum;
cin >> N;
int largest = 0;
int loop_count = 0;
for (int i =0 ;i < N;i++){
    cin >> arr[i];
}
for(int i = 0;i<N-1;i++){
    loop_count ++;
    for (int j = i + 1;i<N;j++){
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
            sum = 0;
            for (int k = i; k < j;k++){//I think the problem in this line
                sum += arr[k];
            if (sum > largest){
                largest = sum;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
//it doesn't cout
cout << "Number of loop: "<<loop_count<<endl;
cout << "Largest sum all number between 2 same number: "<<largest ;
```

Please help me because I have a text next month ;-;
I fixed it 1 time but notthing happed

Comment: Well this is because see, you're initialising j=i+1 and then you're setting k=i and then you loop it till k<j i.e while i<i+1 and on the next step you're doing i++ now that becomes i+1<i+1 and i+1==i+1 not less than i so it breaks (I've written the values of k and j in terms of i)                         [and that's the loop on which you said you think the problem is]

Comment: Seems like a typo for `for (int j = i + 1; j < N; ++j)`